# Scaffold-DbContext does not check-out updated files in TFS

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, tfs, entity-framework-core

I've done some ALTER changes in the database then I performed the scaffold command to update my model as follows: `Scaffold-DbContext "Server=localhost;Database=<DB_NAME>;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models\Domain -Force -Project <PROJECT_NAME>`.

When I check the model in my project I can see the change in code but files are marked as unchanged in the source control so I have to check-out all updated classes myself.

Is there a way to make the scaffold action auto check-out changes in file?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT of course not, the updated files are c# models (classes) which are not excluded.

Also, whenever I edit in these files in the IDE (by manually entering or removing text) it is marked as changes in TFS

Comment: Which version of TFS and VS/Team Explorer do you use? Do you use [local workspace or server workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/decide-between-using-local-server-workspace?view=azure-devops)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using `Server workspace`, as with a `Server workspace`, modifying a file outside of Visual Studio, TFS doesn't seem to detect the change to the file.

It's suggested to use `Local Workspace`, with `Local workspace`, when you modify files outside Visual Studio, your workspace should be able to detect the changes automatically.

If you still want to use `Server workspace`, you would need to check out the file manually or do a compare to find the modified files, check following cases:

- [How to have TFS 2010 detect changes done to files outside of Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899213/how-to-have-tfs-2010-detect-changes-done-to-files-outside-of-visual-studio)
- [Force TFS to detect changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16339983/force-tfs-to-detect-changes)

Comment: Thank you very much. Apologies for my late reply I had a problem with my account and I couldn't login to see your comment.