# How to automate excluding deleted files on checkin?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

I have a VERY large project which just went through an upgrade process. The upgrade is a process external to Visual Studio. As a result, files that are deleted by the upgrade process do not get properly detected by TFS so TFS pukes on checkin saying that it can't find the file.

The problem is that there are several *hundred* files that need to be excluded to resolve the issue. I could do this for days before I'm done. I'm pretty sure my boss would prefer it not take several days.

Is there a quick way to find and automate the exclusion of these files so I can just be done with it?

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? If you switch to using a local workspace this is handeled for you..

Comment: TFS online through visualstudio.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options...

1. **Use a Local Workspace** - if you go into the settings of your Workspace you can change it from Server to Local. This will allow the changes to be detected automatically. You may need to copy everything out and then back in if you have already made the changes...
2. **Reconcile the difference** - You can use the TFS 2013 Power Tools and the "tfpt online /adds /deletes /diff /noprompt /recursive directory-name" command...[How to have TFS 2010 detect changes done to files outside of Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899213/how-to-have-tfs-2010-detect-changes-done-to-files-outside-of-visual-studio)

Comment: I love the idea of reconciling. Thanks!

Comment: I'm wary about changing how TFS actually recognizes the project because it seems to be finicky and want to replace all my work with current server versions on a regular basis... but I'll start by looking at that option. Thanks for the heads up on that.

Comment: It's not finicky, it's solid, tried and tested. VSTS is about as solid as they come and any problems are general due to unsupported workflows.