# Whats the easiest and noob friendly way to move changes from github to tfs?

Tags: github, tfs

I have a project hosted on TFS, let's call it GenderBlender. Two teams work on GenderBlender. One team got the latest code from TFS and hosted it on Github. Made some commits to that GitHub. How can I move those changes from Github to Tfs without commit history and just one big commit under my account?

Comment: Are you moving it to Git, or to TFVC?

Comment: I will be moving it from my local git repository to my local tfs repository and then committing them to the tfs.

Comment: That didn't answer my question -- "tfs" is not a version control system. Are you using a TFVC repository hosted in TFS, or a Git repository hosted in TFS?

Comment: TFVC repository

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I will be moving it from my local git repository to my local tfs repository and then committing them to the tfs.

That is actually the idea: copy the all files from the Git repo to the tfs working tree ([be it a TFVC workspace or a Git one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/comparison-git-tfvc?view=azure-devops))

- If it is a Git repo, Git will detect the changes: add and commit.
- If it is a TFVC workspace, use a [reconcile command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22860674/6309) to detect the changes